# Accessing some form of unique identifier from the inside of program execution

Tags: solana-program

Is there a way to access some form of a unique identifier for the transaction that's currently executing from the BPF execution context(program code)?

I have two options in mind, but I haven't been able to find how to access them:

1. Transaction hash
2. Current slot + current tick

As far as I understand, the current slot by itself isn't sufficient because there can be multiple transactions during the same slot.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If uniqueness is the only concern, I suggest creating an account that stores a number, and incrementing that number by one whenever the tx succeeds (rollover to 0 on overflow). Now you can concat slot + this number, and if multiple txes occur in one slot, they will still have a unique identifier.

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
pub struct UniqueID {
    /// Struct version number
    pub version: u16,
}

// In your handler...
let unique_id: u128 = (Clock::get().unwrap().slot << 64) as u128 & (version as u128);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it sounds interesting! My main concern with it: let's imagine an instruction with high throughput using this incrementing nonce, with many transactions requiring this account with the write permission. Wouldn't it cause problems?

Comment: Let's say this tx is processed several times in the same block and it comes from different callers. The validator that handles that block will process the transactions in whatever order they want, but it will process them sequentially. So each id will be unique, but you can't guarantee the order. As for write access, consider a simpler transfer ix: you can send as many as you want in the same tx, no issue if they alter the same accounts.